# Windows 10 upgrade hangs on FIRST BOOT with spinning circle

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I have an older Windows 7 Professional x86 install that I am trying to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional. Hardware is a mini-ITX with i3 4170, 4400 HD graphics, 4gb memory and 250gb SSD. The install was originally Windows 95 OSR2, possibly upgraded to Windows 98, then upgraded to Windows 2000, XP, Vista and finally 7.

The installation halts on the first boot, after the files have been copied, with the black screen, Windows logo and spinning circle.

I have been trying to upgrade this install for nearly three years. Is there some way to debug the upgrade process to find what's blocking FIRST BOOT?

Comment: Whew! A real museum piece. Windows 10 has removed some old drivers from the installation, so there may not be any supported drivers for your computer. If you are still determined, make sure Windows 7 is fully patched, then run the [Windows 10 upgrade checker](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/8/0/C8007C4E-D1DD-4922-A966-3A927E86A033/GWXWebWindows.exe).

Comment: The hardware is circa-2015, with a mini-ITX  motherboard and i3 4170 Socket 1150.

Comment: Circa-2015 with Windows 95? No way. More like 1995.

Comment: You could try booting into safe mode in the hope that this minimal set of drivers will allow you to run. Then you can play with the drivers or/and look into the c:\windows\ntbtlog.txt file...

Comment: The hardware was upgraded over the years, along with the OS. It's currently a Socket 1150 mini-ITX with DDR3 memory.

Is it possible to boot SAFE MODE during an upgrade? Meanwhile, I"ll have a look at ntbtlog.txt. (Thanks!)

Comment: I believe I've misread you a little bit. I thought you managed to upgrade, but when booting for the first time then Windows hung..

Comment: No, the stoppage occurs when the Windows 10 upgrade attempts FIRST BOOT (stage 3). In the end, the upgrade reverts to Windows 7.

Comment: It's getting too late here, but here's some other log files that _may_ be of help to you; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928901/log-files-that-are-created-when-you-upgrade-to-a-new-version-of-window

Comment: You might need to format the disk for clean installation.

Comment: The logs link may help, thanks.

Regarding formatting the disk, that's not necessary. The upgrade will succeed if neither files and settings nor programs are preserved. Somewhere in there is what's blocking the upgrade.

Comment: *if neither files and settings nor programs are preserved* so, what's the difference between that and a clean install as suggested? Easy answer: Time and reliability. A clean install is faster and more reliable. Consider that.

Comment: I'm trying to find out what is blocking this upgrade.

Comment: Pretty much anything can. And not the least a 32-bit OS running on modern(ish) 64-bit UEFI hardware. Even within Windows 10 alone and between its several versions/builds there are notorious differences and any feature update can fail and some often do in many different machines. But you seems to have too much free time - *I have been trying to upgrade this install for nearly three years* - so you may find out the specific cause eventually. Good luck.

Comment: It doesn't matter which hardware is used: these old 32-bit XP installs upgraded from Windows 2000 or Windows 9X refuse to in-place upgrade to 10 unless programs and settings are not migrated.

Comment: I know the thread is dinosaur old but I have exactly the same problem. I virtualized a Windows NT 4.0 SP6 and then upgraded to XP, Vista and then to 7. All with more or less problems but successfully. Now when I update to Windows 10, Windows 10 hangs on FIRST BOOT. Just like with you. Could you solve the problem then?

Comment: It will upgrade if you choose not to migrate programs and settings.